# Few keys suddenly stopped working altogether!

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, drivers, keyboard, windows-7

I have been running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 on my Dell Vostro 1015. The system is running 32 bit version of the OSs and has 4GB of RAM.

Everything was running smooth until one day when in Windows, a few of my keyboard keys stopped working, all of a sudden.

To be specific, they are {+ - 5 6 LeftCtrl} and a few function keys.

Well, I found that, this isnt a new issue, hence ruled out the hardware fault, as many people have been successful in getting it working back on.

Then I tried each and every solution available on various forums, but none worked out.

Now, when I booted into Ubuntu, to my surprise same issue exists here.

Interestingly, my CPU fan has also stopped spinning since that very moment.

I find it really hard to beleive for it to be a multiple hardware failure.

Kindly help me in getting things working.

Please pardon me for my verbose post (it is my first post here)

Thank you.

Comment: It reads like hardware issue to me (and off-topic as OS is not part of the hardware).  You've described the problem on two different OSes, so it's not like the OS itself. Normally I'd suggest booting a *live* system & testing there (esp. a *live* system using different software/stack to your installed OSes)  You could explore with `xev` but again that won't help much if it's hardware as I suspect (does it work in the BIOS where only hardware/firmware is functional?)

Comment: CPU fan is your main problem that needs to be fixed.  Same problem in both OSs is a hardware fault.  You have two, might have had a power surged.

Comment: Thank you for the response @guiverc @crip659. I booted FreeDOS through USB, the problem persisted. As a matter of fact, today a few more keys failed at random. I inspected the CPU fan manually; it was free to rotate and was not clogged with dust. Interestingly, on running `pwmconfig`, I got a message that the fan sensors have failed. I also reflashed the BIOS, but nothing improved. So, it is indeed a multiple hardware failure all at once. **But what amazes me is the fact that many people have faced the exact sequence of key failures (i.e. 5, 6, +, -) and have somehow rectified the same**

Answer (score 0):

Since the same exact problem exists in both Windows **and** Ubuntu, it's extremely **unlikely that it's a software issue** causing the problem.

Instead, it's likely that **you have a firmware or hardware problem**.

Since keyboards rarely have firmware, the most likely explanation is that your keyboard is broken or perhaps it needs to be cleaned.

FYI: You are using an EOL operating system that needs to be replaced ASAP (Win7).  Ubuntu 16.04 is also getting close to EOL in a few months.  This might be a good opportunity to upgrade/reinstall your system.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Nmath. I updated UBUNTU to the latest available version and also reflashed the BIOS, but the problem persists. I also tried FreeDOS in USB but again, the same set of keys failed to work. So, it is indeed a hardware failure. However, I am amazed that many people have faced the failure of exactly same set of keys (5, 6, +, -) and have rectified the issue by entering some Key Combinations like `Ctrl + Alt + Win/Fn`.